# Flutter Unsupported class file major version 63 Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm getting error after update the Android version and flutter version. Right now I want add the "file_picker: ^5.2.5", and "cached_network_image: ^3.2.3" plugin so getting "General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63" error.
I have checked many solution but nothing one to help me.
Please help me for fix this issue.

**Flutter version:-**
Flutter 3.3.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18a827f393 (4 months ago) • 2022-09-28 10:03:14 -0700
Engine • revision 5c984c26eb
Tools • Dart 2.18.2 • DevTools 2.15.0

**Android Studio version:-**
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry:
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.github.dhaval2404.material_icon_generator (1.3)
Dart (221.6091)
pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker (1.3.5)
io.flutter (71.2.4)

[image]

Comment: Please add error as code.

Comment: In the screenshot all are covered.

Answer (score 19):

[I finally found the solution of this problem :-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCu2r.jpg)

soo just go at your project folder and then
open android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties then change this :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

To This :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

and then your issue get solved

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr Update Android Studio and Gradle Versions

I encountered this error while trying to run [Flutter integration tests on Firebase Test Lab](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#android-device-testing). I was able to solve this by updating a few things in Android Studio.

#### Update the Project's JDK

1. Open the Android Studio Project Structure page (File -> Project Structure)
2. Click the "SDKs" tab
3. Download the newest JDK version and add it to the list
   [image]
   [image]
4. Click the "Project" tab
5. Update the SDK field to the new JDK
   [image]

#### Update com.android.tools.build:gradle

In android/build.gradle, update the com.android.tools.build:gradle value to the latest version found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google).

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
        ...
    }
```

#### Update the gradle distributionUrl

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, update the distributionUrl property to use the [latest Gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases/).

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to this location(C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr)
2. Copy all the files from here
3. paste all the copied files in (jre) folder
4. Open your cmd and run flutter doctor again.

Answer (score 0):

Check flutter doctor status. The issue likely is in the java bundle.

Comment: Yes but how can i fix this issue. Please suggest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).