# flutter VS code problem : Can't use Java 19 and Gradle 7.5 to import Gradle project android

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, visual-studio-code

for evry project i do on vs code this problem happens. it comes form android folder in flutter project files, but the program runs well and it has no affection on excution or build the app,and also this problem appers :
(*The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'D:\Flutter\setup\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 63
Unsupported class file major version 63*),
and it happens only on vs code but when i open the project on andoid studio there isn't any problem.how can i solve it.

this is flutter doctor summary

```
*flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448], locale en-GB)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.*
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Unsupported class file major version 63 Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155059/flutter-unsupported-class-file-major-version-63-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 7.5 is too old to be run with Java 19. As per [Gradle's Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), you need at least Gradle 7.6 to run it with Java 19.

I'd suggest you to use Gradle 8.4 - the latest stable version as of now.

You can also take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137886#issuecomment-1793852741). In general, it's good to use the latest stable versions of native tooling.